# unable to create a constant value of type anonymous type only primitive types

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework Version=6.0.0.0 to get to get common id and orderid as shown below.

```
var dt1 = from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
          select new
          {
              Id = p.Field<int>("Id"),
              OrderId = p.Field<int>("OrderId")
          };

var dt2 = (from order in db.Orders
           select new
           {
               order.Id,
               order.OrderId
           }).ToList();
var intersect = dt1.Intersect(dt2);
```

Based on the list of values in intersect. I need to select all the values from Orders Table.

Trying to used code getting error "unable to create a constant value of type anonymous type only primitive types"

```
var result= (from a in sync.Orders
              where intersect.Any(b => a.Id == b.Id && a.OrderId == b.OrderId)
              select a).ToList();
```

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL, EF, something else?

Comment: using Entity Framework.

Comment: Please include that in the question then - ideally with EF version information.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are trying to "join" an EF query with an in-memory data set, which does not work because there's not a way to embed the list and the lookup in SQL.  One option is to pull the entire table into memory with `AsEnumerable`:

```
var result= (from a in sync.Orders.AsEnumberable
              where intersect.Any(b => a.Id == b.Id && a.OrderId == b.OrderId)
              select a).ToList();
```

Another option is to concatenate the `Id` and `OrderId` into one value and use `Contains` since that can be translated to an `IN` clause in SQL:

```
var lookup = intersect.Select(i => i.Id + "-" + i.OrderId).ToList();

var result= (from a in sync.Orders
              where lookup.Contains(a.Id + "-" + a.OrderId)
              select a).ToList();
```

Comment: Helped me solve an entirely separate problem.  Nice one @d-stanley!